# How to use unix executable file if double clicking it doesnt work?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

I'm very new to using terminal on mac and was wondering if anyone can help with the issue I'm having.

I want to use a command that I downloaded but when I double-click this shows up. The terminal window then freezes and when I try to call the command from new shell, then it just says the command can't be found. Would really appreciate some help. Thank you!

```
Last login: Mon Jun  1 20:37:34 on ttys000 
/Users/harinlee/Downloads/sonic-annotator-1.5-osx-amd64/sonic-annotator ; exit;
(base) Harins-MacBook-Pro:~ harinlee$ /Users/harinlee/Downloads/sonic-annotator-1.5-osx-amd64/sonic-annotator ; exit;
sonic-annotator: no transform(s) specified
sonic-annotator: use -h or --help option for help
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

Comment: What exacty did you download (and where from)? What do you double-click?

Comment: PS: Also, please copy-paste text from Terminal and apply code formatting to make it accessible to people with screenreaders and to the search function.

Comment: @nohillside Thanks for letting me know about the format. It's the exec file that I double-clicked to execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is meant for command line use, you should type all the required info *in the command line*. For more help, run these two commands in Terminal app.

```
cd ~/Downloads/sonic-annotator-1.5-osx-amd64
./sonic-annotator --help
```

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/397524/what-does-the-mean-dot-slash-in-linux/397528#397528
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4432/359891

Many tools provide `README`, `docs` or similar files which contain examples of usage.

Also I found the examples of usage in the online docs here, in case anyone wants to check it out:

- https://code.soundsoftware.ac.uk/projects/sonic-annotator/wiki

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried these commands but it would return `sonic-annotator: command not found`. The exec file that I want to run is in that folder you provided above.

Comment: The `README` file wasn't helpful as it assumes that the user can get this utility program to run.

Comment: @HarinLee See the updated answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/392725/revisions

Comment: RE: "Note that if the file `sonic-annotator` is not an executable, you'll have to specify the path to it, which we did here by `./`" -- That _statement_ is not accurate! If a file isn't _executable_ then its _execute bit_ needs to be _set_, e.g., `chmod +x sonic-annotator`. On the other hand, if it's already _set_ and if it's not in a _directory_ as defined in the `PATH` _shell variable_ then use either the _fully qualified pathname_ of the _command_, or _change directory_ to where it's located and prepend the _command_ with: `./`

Comment: @user3439894 fixed. feel free to add any more info, if you wish